# C# Listview adds an extra column header in Details view

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, columnheader

I have ListView, where I'm adding just 2 columns with some data. the view I have set is details view.When I run the application, I see a third column header in the end, which appears to be an extra column. So how can I avoid this third column/ column header coming in the output and just show 2 columns.

Comment: It's not a column, it's empty space after the last column to fill the header. Set width of the last column to `-2`, this way it will fill the hearer. Setting to`-2` in fact changed the size to fill the header but it will not get applied automatically again if the size of other column or list view change. You can switch to `DataGridView` control for better user/developer experience.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you do not see an extra column, but that your ListView simply is wider than your two columns.

Make sure your two columns take up all the space in your listview by either making them wider or setting up the last column (your second one) to use up all available horizontal space (something like width="*" or so).

Comment: I know, it allows user to expand the second column manually. I tried setting the width of the second column to '-2' as some sites suggested, but for me it shrinks that column such that it won't be visible. :P

Comment: If you want users to be able to make the column wider, then you will Always have that extra space that looks like a third column. Why not make it full-width and let the user  change the width of the _first_ column instead?